# Zoom without Ctrl

Tags: adobe-xd, zoom, figma

Zoom in and out without the need to hold down **crtl** key would make navigation much easier and faster.
It is really a question why **developers/UI/UX designers** of many of design softwares do not pay attention to this important fact that the user might do zoom in and out hundreds of times in a day and forcing him/her to hold down the **ctrl** or **alt** key all the time is tiresome and less productive.
Hope they understand this important fact and do accordingly to solve the problem like what **Inkscape** and **Gimp** have done to make it possible to choose the preferred settings.

**Question**
Is there a way one could achieve this in **adobe xd** or in **figma**? Tried **AutoHotKey** software to convert **mouse scroll** to **ctrl down + mouse scroll** but it skips some steps and moves the screen up and down between some steps.
Is there any **plugin** or any different approach to make it possible to **zoom** in and out without the need to keep **ctrl** or any other modifer key down?

*Appreciate your share of knowledge.*

Answer (score 1):

Making a huge assumption here based on the professionals i've worked with but, most designers i've come across in general have their hand sitting still in the left corner of the keyboard, myself included, as most of the relevant shortcuts are around that area.  *(Ctrl (shift) S, Ctrl C, Ctrl V, Ctrl Z, Ctrl (Alt/Shift) E, Ctrl Alt C, Ctrl T, Ctrl R, Q, Ctrl A, Ctrl D... just to name a few)*

Clicking Command/Ctrl/Alt/Shift several times a day is practically natural, possibly more natural than scrolling.

But on top of that, neutral scrolling does scroll like you'd expect the scroll wheel to behave: it scroll things up and down like a web page. Which is probably the reason behind the decision of having zoom-in/out bound to the Ctrl key, afterall that's also the behaviour of Ctrl + Mousewheel in browsers. And since AdobeXD is for interfaces and web is probably the most ubiquitous interface nowdays, it feels more natural that it behaves like one.

The only situation i've seen mousewheel doing zoom-in/out *out of the box as the default* was in 3D software.

Answer (score 0):

On windows, you can use + and - buttons on numpad to zoom in and out without modifier keys.

For all shortcuts click here https://shortcuts.design/toolspage-figma.html